# Symfony Routes only working in frontend_dev (1.4.12)

Tags: url-routing, symfony-1.4

Hi guys I'm having a strange symfony problem.

I'm developing currently on my localhost and when I turn of frontend_dev no route is working anymore. Just the index ://

I'll make an example for you to specify my problem:

localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php/ -> shows the index
localhost:8080                   -> shows the index

localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php/some_route -> shows where its going
localhost:8080/some_route                  -> URL not found on this server.

My question is: How can I get my page to work again without constantly frontend_deving?

Comment: Can you post your routing.yml?

Comment: When you say "anymore," you imply that it worked before... what changed? If you're not using revision control, do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. My problem was the switch to a new apache which had `mod_rewrite` disabled.

Answer (score 1):

When you link to a route in your view, you should always use the built-in helper functions like `url_for()` and `link_to()`. These functions use the `settings.yml` and `routing.yml` to generate the routes.

When you use this structure, you can easily change an url by updating it in the `routing.yml`, and then automatically all URL's are updated in the view.

Also, by setting the `no_script_name` setting in the `settings.yml` (for your selected environment) the `frontend_dev.php` (frontend controller) is automatically prepended when needed.

Comment: You can read this chapter : http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/09-Links-and-the-Routing-System  
The url rewriting part deals with your problem.

Comment: well yeah i only use link_to or url_for, every link goes like link_to('mainpage', '@homepage'); anyway heres the routing yml:
http://nopaste.me/paste/11418380824ead7fff504d5